# NSMutableDictionary entries uncomplete by init with arrays of Keys and Objects

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, key, nsdictionary

im a litte confused by adding two NSMutableArrays to an NSMutableDictonary,
one for Keys and one for Objects.
This is working as long the Keys are not the same

If there are even, I only get the last object in my Dict.

If I change my Keys to my Objects and Objects to Keys, everything works fine.

Can anyone help me with that?

Here are my Outputs:

```
2012-12-08 19:30:40.906 Test[12015:c07] myKeys: (
"Bauchumfang & Gewicht",
"Bauchumfang & Gewicht",
"Stress & Entspannung",
"Stress & Entspannung",
"Mein Rauchverhalten",
"Mein Rauchverhalten",
"Blutdruck & Puls",
"Blutdruck & Puls",
"Blutzucker & Diabetes",
"Blutzucker & Diabetes",
"Meine Stimmung",
"Meine Stimmung",
"R\U00fccken & Bewegung",
"R\U00fccken & Bewegung",
"R\U00fccken & Bewegung",
Schlafrhythmus,
Schlafrhythmus,
"Schrittz\U00e4hler"
)
2012-12-08 19:30:40.907 Test[12015:c07] myObjects: (
"Mein Bauchumfang",
"Mein Gewicht",
"Mein Entspannungsniveau",
"H\U00e4ufigkeit der Entspannungsmomente",
Rauchverhalten,
"Verlangen nach einer Zigarette",
"Systolischer Wert",
"Diastolischer Wert",
"Meine bewusste Ern\U00e4hrung mit Diabetes",
"Meine Blutzucker-Werte",
"Mein Befinden",
"Meine Aktivit\U00e4ten",
"Umsetzung meiner R\U00fccken\U00fcbungen",
"Das Befinden meines R\U00fcckens",
"Meine sportlichen Aktivit\U00e4ten",
"Meine Schlafqualit\U00e4t",
"Mein Energieniveau",
"Meine Schritte"
)
2012-12-08 19:30:40.907 Test[12015:c07] myDictionary: {
"Bauchumfang & Gewicht" = "Mein Gewicht";
"Blutdruck & Puls" = "Diastolischer Wert";
"Blutzucker & Diabetes" = "Meine Blutzucker-Werte";
"Mein Rauchverhalten" = "Verlangen nach einer Zigarette";
"Meine Stimmung" = "Meine Aktivit\U00e4ten";
"R\U00fccken & Bewegung" = "Meine sportlichen Aktivit\U00e4ten";
Schlafrhythmus = "Mein Energieniveau";
"Schrittz\U00e4hler" = "Meine Schritte";
"Stress & Entspannung" = "H\U00e4ufigkeit der Entspannungsmomente";
}
```

and my implementation:

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader
didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {

  menuItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  for (Trackers *trackers in objects) {

    if ([trackers.assigned isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        [menuItems addObject:[trackers name]];
        [groups addObject:[trackers category]];
    }

  }
  NSLog(@"myKeys: %@", groups);
  NSLog(@"myObjects: %@", menuItems);
  NSMutableDictionary *menuGroups = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
  initWithObjects:menuItems forKeys:groups];
  NSLog(@"myDictionary: %@", menuGroups);
  [menuList addObject:menuGroups];
  contentLoaded = YES;
  [settingsTable reloadData];
}
```

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well a dictionary per definition doesnt allow duplicate keys
upon looking at your code, you want to store N items under the same key.

to do so you need store an array of items for each key.. UNTESTED example (written inline)

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader
didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects {
  NSMutableDictionary *menuGroups = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  for (Trackers *trackers in objects) {

    if ([trackers.assigned isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [menuGroups objectForKey:[trackers category]];
        if(!array) {
            array = [NSMutableArray array];
            [menuGroups setObject:array forKey:[trackers category]];
        }
        [array addObject:[trackers name]];
    }

  }


  contentLoaded = YES;
  [settingsTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: the keys are treated as a SET

Comment: the tableview should treat each value in the dict as a section and each element in the ARRAY as a row in that section!

Comment: This works absolute fine! Thank you! another question by the way: how can I count all objects of one key in the dict?

Comment: NSUInteger countOfThisKey = [[dict objectForKey:@"MYKEYNAME"] count]